# How to recognize two different objects with the similar shape, but different size

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, computer-vision

I am using Mask-RCNN neural network. I retrained my network to detect and mask wheels of die-cast toy cars. I am using images, which present the side of the car (left or right).

Sometimes the cars have different sizes of the wheels like presented on the image below. The front wheels are much smaller than rear ones. I want to detect front ones as "front wheels" and rear one as "rear wheels". If there is only one wheel on the photo (caused by bad cropping), then I want to detect this wheel just as a "wheel".

What should I do to mask 2 wheels (and assing proper labels to them) if image contains two wheels, which looks similiar?

[Car image](https://i.etsystatic.com/15065017/r/il/d4c0bd/1458687225/il_1588xN.1458687225_6jsk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Mask-RCNN can segment each instance of object separately irrespective of size of object. It does not classify object based on perspective, it will classify both wheels as wheels.

If you train model with two classes like front and rear wheel it will work fine when the condition is true, but when the wheels will be of same size it won't produce expected output.

You can train two different models for different set of cars, like if the car has different size wheels, then it will classify the wheels as front and rear wheel which will be the next module. This segmentation and classification will be based on logic that rear wheel of car will always be bigger in size than front wheels but never the small. But if the car is not classified in that category, then the wheels will not be segmented by size, in which case    it will classify them as only wheels.

Answer (score 0):

[Model output of Mask-RCNN](https://github.com/multimodallearning/pytorch-mask-rcnn/blob/master/demo.py) provides **bounding boxes**. Why not using those bounding boxes to infer the size of each tire and compare the tire sizes? Then you can label them as front or rear based on their **area**.

```
# Run detection
results = model.detect([image])

# Visualize results
r = results[0]
visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'],
                            class_names, r['scores'])
```

You can use the `r['rois']` for computation of the areas of tires as following:

```
y1, x1, y2, x2 = rois[i]

area[i] = (y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2
```

Then only thing left is to decide which area is larger.